# How to calculate $51! \ mod \ 101$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, factorial

I tried almost everything I know
Even tried to calculate it from Wilson's theorem and what I got was
$$(101-50)! \equiv 51! \equiv (101 + 49!)^{-1} mod \ 101$$

I derived it from 
$$(p-1)! \equiv -1 \ mod \ p$$
$$(p-2)! \equiv 1 \ mod \ p$$
$$(p-3)! \equiv (p-2)^{-1} \ mod \ p$$
$$(p-4)! \equiv (p+6)^{-1} \ mod \ p$$
and so on...

but calculating right side is as hard as calculating left side and I can't just do it with my pen and paper. Am I going in right direction? I would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: BTW you can use \pmod as in $(p-1)!\equiv-1 \pmod p$ `$(p-1)!\equiv-1 \pmod p$` or $a\equiv b\pmod{101}$ `$a\equiv b\pmod{101}$` See TeX.SE for more about this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137073/writing-mod-in-congruence-problems-without-leading-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use equality ($=$) through for $\ \equiv \pmod{101}$ - it saves typing.

By Wilson's Theorem, $-1 = 100!$. Recall Wilson's Theorem states that $-1 \equiv (p-1)! \pmod{p}$ for prime $p$.

$$100! = 1 \times 2 \times \dots \times 50 \times \underbrace{51}_{-50} \times \dots \times \underbrace{99}_{-2} \times \underbrace{100}_{-1}$$

That is, $100!$ is $$\underbrace{1 \times 2 \times \dots \times 50}_{50!} \times \underbrace{50 \times 49 \times \dots \times 2 \times 1}_{50!} \times \underbrace{(-1)^{50}}_{1} = (50!)^2$$

Now, $50! \times 51 = 51!$, so

$$\underbrace{51! \times 51^{-1}}_{50!} \times \underbrace{51! \times 51^{-1}}_{50!} = (50!)^2 = 100! = -1$$

so
$$(51!)^2 \times 51^{-2} = -1$$

whence

$$(51!)^2 = -51^2$$

Now, we can work out $-51^2$ manually as $25$, so we obtain $(51!)^2 = 25 = 5^2$. Since $x^2 = y^2 \Rightarrow x = \pm y$, we obtain that $51! = \pm 5$.

Now, is it +5 or -5? Still thinking about that one.

Comment: Ah, thank you, now I'm getting the picture.  I really appreciate your taking the time to lay out the steps and reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

We already know that $100! \equiv -1$ (mod $101$).

Moreover, we have $i \equiv -(101-i)$ (mod $101$), for $1\leq i\leq 50$. Then, one has $50! \equiv (-1)^{50} 51\times 52\times \dots \times 100$, it implies that $50! \equiv 10$ (mod $101$) or $50! \equiv 91$ (mod $101$). But $50! \not\equiv 10$ (mod $101$) (Someone helps me?). So, we get $51! \equiv 91\times 51 \equiv -5$ (mod $101$).

Comment: Where the heck does 100!=-1(mod 101) come from?

Comment: @JerryGuern It's Wilson's Theorem.

Comment: Who is the "we" in "we already know".  Please try to post Answers that non-experts in the field might conceivably be able to follow.

Comment: @JerryGuern This is really basic, to be brutally honest. Wilson's theorem was in the second lecture I ever had on modular arithmetic. I'm posting an answer with more explanation, give me a minute.

Comment: @PatrickStevens  Yes, I'm sure this is all pretty basic--to people who have had classes on modular arithmetic.  But there are feeeew people on SE who haven't.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you knew Wilson's theorem from the fact that you said you tried to use it in your question :)

Comment: To be precise - I asked this question, not Jerry :)

Comment: @Chris - oops, that is definitely my bad :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is a computer program.  In matlab:

x=1;

for n=1:51

x = mod(x*n,101);

end

x

Answer (score 0):

$100!=1.2.3...50.(-50).(-49)...(-1)\pmod{101}$

Comment: Why downvoted? it is a good idea :)

Comment: I can't make any sense of this Answer either.  A few words of explanation would be helpful.

Comment: $-1 = 100! = 51! (-1)^{50} 51! 51^{-2} = (51!)^2 51^{-2}$, so $-51^2 = (51!)^2$. The left-hand side is easily found to be $25$, so $51!$ squares to 25. That is, it's $\pm 5$. That gets it to the point of GAVD's answer above.

Comment: @PatrickStevens  -51^2 definitely does not equal (51!)^2.

Comment: @JerryGuern Congruence mod 101, as I hoped was indicated by the statement that $-1 = 100!$.

Comment: Sorry , but why we have $51^{-2}$ in the third congruency term ? @PatrickStevens

Comment: @PatrickStevens  i couldn't follow a single step of your derivation, nor could I make sense of this Answer or the one below.  Super-short posts that explain nothing and assume of the field are not useful.

Comment: I really wish someone would spend two minutes typing out a useful explanation of this.

Comment: @JerryGuern I've spent the minutes. Don't know if it's useful.

Comment: Thanks @Patrick.  We already had Wilson's Theorem in the comments.  Apart from that, I used that $51=-50\pmod{101}$, and so on.  Then, I hadn't thought it through, that the equation, as you derived it, is still a quadratic.

Comment: @PatrickStevens  I saw it, thanks!